# Log in Sonata system user

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I have a Sonata application and am trying to import some data from a csv.

When trying to persist data from a service called via a CLI command, I get the following exception:

> [Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException]
>   The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall c   onfigured for this URL.

How do I log in the system user from my program?

Answer (score 0):

I found this shortly after posting.

```
private function loginAsSystemUser()
{
    $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
    $user = $userRepository->getUserByUsername('system');
    $token = new PreAuthenticatedToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
}
```